# FileSystemWatcher and network disconnect?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, filesystemwatcher

How can I make it work in a network? It works then it stops working without reason (maybe because the network isn't perfect).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to reconnect with FileSystemWatcher.

Make your variable of type FileSystemWatcher global to your class, add the event WatcherError.

Inside the method, add something like that :

```
  private static void WatcherError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
  {
     watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();//You might want to do a method and to setup all config...
     while (!watcher.EnableRaisingEvents)
     {
        try
        {
           watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();//You might want to do a method and to setup all config...
        }
        catch
        {
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000); //Wait for retry 30 sec.
        }
     }
  }
```

You do not want to use watcher = new... you would prefer to have a method that will add all event and setup the path but the code above give you a good idea of what to do.

Comment: This code is not reliable because FileSystemWatcher not always fire Error event when network folder or drive is monitored.

Comment: When the Network is down, an error show. What is the situation where it's not reliable?

Comment: If FileSystemWatcher used to monitor network folder, the FileSystemWatcher.Error is not always fired if something goes wrong with network. This is known issue and your code will not be executed.

Comment: Do you have any reference? Because I have code that is working with this code for years and it works pretty well. Also, do you have any alternative?