# Handle Filewatcher with network Disconnects

Tags: vb.net

There is alot of post out there about this, all revolving around a common solution. I have attempted to use this solution but do not believe it's as reliable as i had hoped. If anyone could point out what i am doing wrong or suggestions to make it more full proof please post!

Situation: Watching shared network folders..if network is lost, filewatcher loses what it was trying to watch and service dies. The following code does work but not all the time. The event gets fired when it attempts to set the path property of the FS. If the path cant be found(network down) it throws an exception. I catch it and basically sleep for x time and try again. Ideally it sounds like it would work fine but it isn't as reliable as it appears :(

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)

    fs1 = New FileSystemWatcher
    fs1.Filter = My.Settings.MonitoringFilter
    ' fs1.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite
    fs1.Path = My.Settings.MonitoringDirNOSlash
    ' Add event handlers. 
    AddHandler fs1.Error, AddressOf WatcherError
    fs1.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub

Protected Sub WatcherError(source As Object, e As ErrorEventArgs)
    fs1.Dispose()
    fs1 = New FileSystemWatcher
    Dim c As Integer = 0
    While Not fs1.EnableRaisingEvents
        Try
            fs1.Filter = My.Settings.MonitoringFilter
            fs1.Path = My.Settings.MonitoringDirNOSlash
            AddHandler fs1.Error, AddressOf WatcherError
            fs1.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            c += 1
            If c = 1 Then
                ErrorReport(ex.Message)
            End If
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        End Try
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161993/filesystemwatcher-network-disconnect) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376763/filesystemwatcher-is-not-working) answer your question? Using FSW over a network is "a bad idea".   I would skip the more-convenient-but-unreliable FileSystemWatcher and use a [different method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239988/filesystemwatcher-vs-polling-to-watch-for-file-changes).

Comment: i'll look into this polling method. I have alert that gets sent out of the above method fails just so we are notified that the network went down or something else caused the path not be found.

Comment: The polling brought another idea of how to handle this. Can i not just check the connection status of the machine and handle it off that? My question is im not super familiar with service apps...what default method has focus while the service is "started" I know there is the onstart which is used for first iteration instances and settings but after that where could i apply this type of idea to handle connectivity?